# Please explain this answer from MIT 18.02 sc Pset2

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a question from MIT's multi-variable calculus course about equations of planes:

[image]

And the answer is here:

[image]

What I'm struggling to understand is, if we take the component of $OP_0$ in the direction of $N$, then isn't that just the distance from a point that is perpendicular to the plane and **not** the distance from the origin anymore?

Comment: Distance is always measured perpendicular to the plane. Also, how can a *point* be perpendicular to anything?

Comment: Distance between the plane and origin actually means the shortest distance between the two, unless specified otherwise. The shortest distance happens when origin lies on normal to the plane. You are taking component of $OP_0=(x_0-0,y_0-0,z_0-0)$ along $N$ so the distance has to be from $O$, which is origin.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't think of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since  $P_0$  is  a point on the plane,
$$\bigl(\overrightarrow{OP_0}\cdot\overrightarrow N\bigr)\,\frac{\overrightarrow N}{\bigl\|\overrightarrow N\bigr\|^2}$$
is the projection of $\:\overrightarrow{OP_0}\:$ onto the normal to the plane. The norm of this projection is the distance from the origin to the plane, and it is equal to
$$\frac{\bigl|\overrightarrow{OP_0}\cdot\overrightarrow N\bigr|}{\bigl\|\overrightarrow N\bigr\|}.$$